# execute sql statements read from a file

Tags: python, mysql, sql, insert, pyodbc

I want to load text file, which is containing tonnes of sql queries(inserts) and execute it by using Python(PYODBC)

My current code looks like:

```
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
with open('C:\Python_Script_Test\INSERTS.txt','r') as file:
    var1 = file.read().replace("\r\n","")
var2 = var1

cursor.execute(var2)
file.close()
```

there are more then 5000 lines in that file, and sample INSERT from it looks like:

```
Insert into x (q, w, e, r, t, y, u, i, o, p, a, s, d, f, g, h, j)
  VALUES (582, 'GA26', 'TMO ', 'xxx', 'xxx@example.com', '', 'NULL', 'NULL', 
  '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', NULL);
```

error:

```
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: ('42000', 
  "[42000] [MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver][mysqld-5.6.13]
  You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
  your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
  'insert into x
   (z, b, c, d, e' at line 3 (1064) (SQLExecDirectW)")
```

Edit:

Antoher idea:

Ok, there is no errors for this moment. Current code looks like:
    previous = ''
    for sql_insert in  open('C:\Python_Script_Test\x.txt','r'):
        y = sql_insert.strip().replace("\r\n",";")
        if y.startswith('insert'):
            print previous
            if previous.endswith(';'):
                print 'test\r\n'
                cursor.execute(previous)
            previous = y
        else:
            previous += y

BUT, there is no changes on table in database...

Comment: The example line shown from your text file misses a closing parenthesis just before `VALUES`. Start there.

Comment: Seems like you have an error in the INSERTS.txt file on line 3.

Comment: By the way, why go through Python? Normally, you can insert a text file full of SQL commands straight into the database through the database command line.

Comment: @Jite, that is copy - paste mistake, normally I have '(' on my code.

Comment: @Evert, yes I know that, but I have to do that this way.

Comment: @David Dav, the error message says that you have a error in your query, on line 3. Did you copy-paste the wrong error?
Is there any seperator between the insert commands, maybe a missing ;
could try with replace("\r\n", ";"), and are you sure you can run 5000 inserts in one execute?

Comment: Yep Im sure...It works on Workbench ;) But You may be right, executing it by using Python probably force me to do multiple executes...

Comment: "could try with replace("\r\n", ";")" Still the same error...

Comment: "BUT, there is no changes on table in database" You are probably missing a [cnxn.commit()](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#commit) but that should be a different question.

Answer (score 2):

I understand that you must use Python, but it isn't clear that you must execute the entire file at once. Since your input file is already divided into lines, what about:

```
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
with open('C:\Python_Script_Test\INSERTS.txt','r') as inserts:
    for statement in inserts:
        cursor.execute(statement)
```

Also, using `file` as a variable name in Python is a Bad Idea because it overwrites the `file()` built-in.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you forgot closing `)` between `j` and `VALUES`.

At first try executing such line using specialized SQL editor from vendor.

I'm not sure if MySQL ODBC is able to execute many statements at once. If not then you will have to parse input file. If each `INSERT` is in separate file the it is easy:

```
for line in open(...):
    sql_insert = line.strip()
    if sql_insert:
        cursor.execute(sql_insert)
```

If not then you must parse it other way. Maybe split it into statements by using `);`. It depends from your input file.

Comment: pyodbc.Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [MySQL][ODBC 3.51 Driver][mysqld-5.6.13]Query w
as empty (1065) (SQLExecDirectW)')  :/

Comment: OK. Remove empty lines as in edited code. Of course you can also check if line is really `INSERT`: `if sql_insert.startswith('Insert'):` (take care of letters case)

Comment: Are you able to execute single line using MySQL tools?

Comment: Yep. Look at my first post, I have another idea.